# Animation in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

For some reason, my animation only works when executed through an `IBAction` but not through the `viewDidLoad`. I want these images to start animating right when the `view` loads.

```
myImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
                              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"], nil];
[myImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
myImageView.animationDuration = 2;
[myImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: move the code to viewDidAppear or viewWillApear, in viewDidLoad no layout has been done yet.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` will have the same result, because the view WILL appear and i assume the animation shall be visible ;-) `viewDidAppear` is the right place

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move your animation from `viewDidLoad` to `viewDidAppear`. You are not able to animate the components of your view until it has finished laying out.

Answer (score 0):

May be `viewDidLoad` is too late for what you need.

I got the best result with `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.